# Как убрать точки от <li>

Tags: html, css

Как можно убрать это (в неупорядоченном списке `<li>`):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: `ul { list-style: none; }`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Для этой цели применяется стилевое свойство `list-style-type` со значением `none`:

```css
li {
  list-style-type: none;
  /* Убираем маркеры */
}

ul {
  margin-left: 0;
  /* Отступ слева в браузере IE и Opera */
  padding-left: 0;
  /* Отступ слева в браузере Firefox, Safari, Chrome */
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>Север</li>
  <li>Юг</li>
  <li>Запад</li>
  <li>Восток</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Можно сделать изящней то же самое:

```
li {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

Это будет строчно-блочное отображение, маркеры уйдут. Можно просто inline применить.

А можно и блоком оставить список и убрать маркеры:

```
li {
  display: block;
}
```